# Conditions for equivalent definitions of division algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, division-algebras

A division algebra is defined as a (not necessarily finite dimensional, associative, or unital) algebra $A$ over a field, where $\forall a\neq0,b\in A$ the equations $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ have unique solutions. Are all of the following correct?

(1) This definition is equivalent to the maps $L_{a},R_{a}:A\to A$ (defined by left and right multiplication by $a$) having inverse maps.

(2) If $A$ is finite dimensional, then the definition is equivalent to requiring that there be no zero divisors, i.e. $uv=0\Rightarrow u=0$ or $v=0$.

(3) If $A$ is unital, then the definition is equivalent to requiring that unique right and left inverses exist for every non-zero element.

(4) If $A$ is finite dimensional and associative, then $A$ is unital and the left and right inverses are equal, turning the non-zero vectors into a group under multiplication.

The seed of the proof of (2) is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1253278/525270), and I think I understand why the others are true, but [all](https://books.google.com/books?id=2to5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA15) [the](https://books.google.com/books?id=rYePDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA32) [references](https://books.google.com/books?id=OKcKowxXwKkC&pg=PA186) I checked mostly state without proof, so any quick proofs would be nice.

Comment: I think you need to be more precise about what you mean by algebras.  Algebras over what?  Field?  Commutative rings?

Comment: Yes, "algebra" is assumed to be over a field; edited the question to clarify, thanks.